# Bash or Python : Append and prepend a string recursively in all .tex files

Tags: python, bash, append, latex, prepend

I'm trying to find a way to change my master/child document workflow in LaTeX using the package "subfiles", so I'm trying to append and prepend to every file I already have the following lines:

**Lines to prepend:**

```
\documentclass[<mainfile>]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
```

**Line to appen:**

```
\end{document}
```

I was thinking of using bash but I could be nice too with Python, I don't know what would be best.

If you have any suggestion :-) ?

Comment: Editing the files using `sed` would be very fast.

Comment: yes, post the input fragment and expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An intuitive way is to use `cat`

For example, first create two files `prepend.tex` and `append.tex` that contain the content you want to add. Concatenate them with the source file to create the desired target file

```
$ cat prepend.tex source.tex append.tex > target.tex
```

To apply it recursively to all existing files inside a directory say `src/` you can use:

```
$ find src/ -type f -name "*.tex" -exec sh -c "cat prepend.tex '{}' append.tex > '{}'.tmp" \;
```

This will create a new `.tmp` file alongside each source file. Make sure that the result in those `.tmp` files are **exaclty** what you want before proceeding to overwrite the source files with the `.tmp` ones:

```
$ find src/ -type f -name "*.tmp" -exec rename -n 's/.tmp$//' '{}' \;
```

change the option from `-n` to `-f` of the `rename` command to force overwrite

Comment: Wawww that worked super-smooth ! One second of reflexion to trat every files, and feels very much secured to use the temp files (I'll remember this !). MANY thanks !

Comment: @EtienneS Cool, glad that I can help :) By the way, `sed` or `awk` as mentioned by other users can also come in handy in cases when a more complex editing is needed.

Comment: I tried with sed but it was kind of tricky : I'm not yet used to it (have to be!)